# Photoshop Javascript strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, photoshop, flash-cs5, photoshop-script

I'm trying to figure out if it is something wrong with me or the CS5 JavaScript engine.
My Photoshop document have one layer called "A" and a Layer Group called "Group 1".

Consider this example:

```
var Mess = "";
var Layers = app.activeDocument.layers;
alert(Layers.length);
for (n=0; n<app.activeDocument.layers.length; n++) {
  Mess = Mess + app.activeDocument.layers[n].name + "\r\n";
}
alert(Mess);
```

This will show 2 for length and then list the layers:
A
Group 1

Everything fine so far. But if we in the foor loop use the variable Layers instead we get a different result.

```
var Mess = "";
var Layers = app.activeDocument.layers;
alert(Layers.length);
for (n=0; n<Layers.length; n++) {
  Mess = Mess + app.activeDocument.layers[n].name + "\r\n";
}
alert(Mess);
```

As before we get length 2 but now only one layer is listed:
A

Shouldn't the two code examples produce the same result?!?

Comment: Does `alert(app.activeDocument.layers.length)` say 2? It's the only thing different that I see.

Comment: Yes, `alert(app.activeDocument.layers.length)` says 2. But if I access the layers object through a variable it doesn't behaive the same.

Comment: these code produce the same result for me...

Comment: Did you mean `Mess = Mess + Layers[n].name + "\r\n";` is causing trouble? I don't understand enough JS to explain a difference but I remember trying something similar and not liking what I got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Layers` is a reserved word in the Photoshop DOM. [Photoshop CS6 JavaScript Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf)

```
var Mess = "";
var lyrs = app.activeDocument.layers;
alert(lyrs.length);
for (n=0; n<lyrs.length; n++) {
    Mess = Mess + app.activeDocument.layers[n].name + "\r\n";
}
alert(Mess);
```

This seems to work now after changing the name of the variable.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a list of Photoshop DOM reserved words? You where propaply right. When I changed the name it worked.

Comment: Are you using the ExtendScript toolkit as your IDE? If so you can choose `Help > Object Model Viewer` to browse the DOM. Be sure to choose which object library you want to view (Photoshop, Illustrator, etc) from the drop-down menu.

Comment: My ExtendScript Toolkit CS5 is broken, It complains about Line 1 in script 04cdicmanager.jsx so I can't start it. Has been like that from the beginning (fresh installation).